# travis ci publishing to npm only when PR is merged on master

Tags: npm, travis-ci

I'm trying to publish to npm only when a PR is merged on master but the deploy never runs. any help?

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "node"
jobs:
  include:
    - stage: test
      script: 
        - npm test
    - stage: deploy
      provider: npm
      email: $NPM_EMAIL
      api_key: $NPM_API_TOKEN
      skip_cleanup: true
stages:
  - name: test
  - name: deploy
    if: (type = push) AND (branch = master)
```

Answer (score 0):

This took me a while to figure out so I'm posting my answer in case anyone else runs into same issue.

```yaml
language: node_js

node_js:
  - "node"

script: npm test

deploy:
  provider: npm
  email: $NPM_EMAIL
  api_key: $NPM_API_TOKEN
  skip_cleanup: true
  on:
    condition: $TRAVIS_EVENT_TYPE = push #this was the fix
    #tags: true
    branch: master
```